# Framework uses drawRect:; I need to use it on a layer-backed NSView. How to update?

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview, drawrect

According to the documentation for NSView's `drawRect:`

> If your app manages content using its layer object instead, use the updateLayer method to update your layer instead of overriding this method.

I have an `NSView` with subviews that are provided by the framework, and they all draw using `drawRect:`. This framework-provided view is a subview of an `NSView` for which I require a layer. Because my framework-provided view is a descendant of a layer-backed view, `drawRect:` isn't usually called, especially in cases where the window is made active or inactive (the view needs to update to reflect its (in)active state).

Of course if I make my containing view not layer backed, updates occur when the window is made active or inactive.

Without modifying the framework into a custom fork, what's the best avenue for making sure `drawRect:` occurs when needed in my framework-provided view?

Thanks.

Edit 25-Aug-2018:

It looks like the trick is to set one of the views in the hierarchy to, e.g., `[view setCanDrawSubviewsIntoLayer:YES`, which according to the documentation uses all of the subviews’ `drawRect:` to add their drawing to its own layer. However this seems to work only through 10.13, and is broken in the 10.14 beta. I'll continue to look for a potential API change, unless this is a 10.14 beta bug.

Since the issue is still unresolved, it's not really answered yet.

Comment: I think you might be confused. I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but the `-drawRect:` method of a superview is *not* responsible for calling/triggering/invoking the `-drawRect:` of its subviews. Each view (layer or not) gets drawn when it changes, and the magic display manager in Cocoa composites the resulting images. Said another way, the `needsDisplay` state (which eventually cause a new `-drawRect:` message) is independent of its superview and subviews.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that `drawRect:` is responsible for subviews. I'm saying that if I have a view **B** which is drawn via `drawRect:` on a layer-backed view **A**, then my view **B** doesn't have its `drawRect:` called when I focus or unfocus the window. Descendants of layer-backed views become layer-backed, too, thus the documentation quoted indicates `drawRect:` will not be called. If I don't add a layer to view **A**, then my view **B** `drawRect:` is called when needed.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. So why can't your custom `NSView` simply observe its window's `NSWindowDidBecomeMainNotification` and 'NSWindowDidResignMainNotification` notifications and send a `needDisplay=YES` message to all of its subviews? Seems simple (and harmless) enough.

Comment: I don't have a custom `NSView`, unless I want to fork the framework. If I can find a generic solution, then I think a PR would be welcomed, but mostly I'm trying to find the cause and solution for the difference in behavior. There's a difference between hacking it to work, and figuring out what the difference is and doing it the right way. I'm not a paid pro, so I'd prefer to understand what's happening rather than just brute force it.

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't have to subclass the `NSView`. *Any* object can observer a notification and take some action (your window controller, for example). If you think the framework controls are misbehaving when inside a layer-backed view, then definitely file a bug report. But I suspect there's a hack involved...

Comment: I got that, and _maybe_ that's what I'll end up doing if I don't find out how to hook in the automatic behavior. I'll keep checking this question. If I end up taking your approach, I'll be happy to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer-backed views which don't override `-wantsUpdateLayer` to return true still draw themselves using `-drawRect:`. The bit of documentation you quoted is using "should" to mean "should, for best performance,". It's not required, it's just recommended.

Views don't generally redraw themselves just because the containing window has changed key or main status. You would have to mark them as needing display. Or the framework should be doing that.

I suspect the reason that it works when your view is not layer-backed is that you are marking your view as needing update. Since non-layer-backed views draw into the window's backing store using the painter model (back to front), if your view redraws itself then any subviews will have to redraw themselves on top of your view's drawing.

If the framework's views need to redraw when the window's key/main status changes, then they should be observing the relevant notifications and setting themselves as needing display. If they're not doing that, it's a framework bug. You can work around it by marking them as needing display yourself.

Comment: The framework in question is [MMTabBarView](https://github.com/MiMo42/MMTabBarView), and uses NSButton and NSButtonCell descendants, which know how to redraw themselves when the window is made active or inactive, i.e., they're marked dirty automatically. This doesn't seem to be happening automatically, though, when on a layer-backed view. Interestingly, the edit I made to the original question works, but only through 10.13. Although your suggestion/suspicion makes perfect sense, I'll dig into it a bit more.

Comment: Are you doing anything weird with the window's display mechanism (like turning off `autodisplay` or explicitly displaying)? Can you reproduce in a simple test app (to eliminate anything else your app may be doing)?

Comment: Now I'm a little torn... the pragmatic approach and acting on the observation works perfectly, as it should. It lets me move forward, and given that you provided an excellent explanation for the layer-backed behavior, I should mark your answer as accepted. James Bucanek made the same suggestion without posting an answer, though, so I'm unsure of the etiquette here...

Comment: It looks like MMTabBarView has a demo app, which you could tweak to have a layer-backed container view. Also, there was a big update 4 days ago and the commit log includes "Proper appearance when window is not active window". Maybe this is fixed.

Comment: Yeah, that my PR, which works perfectly until I use it with a layer-backed view. I'll accept your answer, because I think you explained the root cause in addition to the pragmatic answer. Thanks!